# Ввод только цифр в инпут

Tags: javascript

Есть задача чтобы пользователи могли ввести в определенные инпуты только цифры. 
Первоначально поставил атрибут onkeyup

```
onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/\D/, '')"
```

Все работает, но дело в том что на странице выводится только 5 таких инпутов и с ними все в порядке. Но есть еще под ними ссылка при нажатии на которую появляются новые инпуты.

```
$(".addingrid").live("click", function(){
    $(this).before("<input onkeyup=\"this.value = this.value.replace (/\D/, '')\" class='kolvo' style='margin-left:7px; margin-right:7px; id='65"+ ingridkolvocount++ +"' type='text' name='PROPERTY[65]["+ ingridcountkolvo++ +"]' size='25' value=''><br/><br/>");
});
```

В новых созданных инпутах ввод только цифр не срабатывает. Как сделать чтобы проверка срабатывала и в новых инпутах?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вместо метода **live()** используем **on()**, в инпутах убираем:

```
onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/\D/, '')"
```

Пишем следующее:

```
$('.kolvo').on('keyup', function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace (/\D/, ''));
});
$(".addingrid").on("click", function(){
    $(this).before("<input class='kolvo' id='65"+ ingridkolvocount++ +"' type='text' name='PROPERTY[65]["+ ingridcountkolvo++ +"]' value=''><br/><br/>");
});
```

И стили лучше прописать в отдельном файле. "*Котлеты отдельно, мухи отдельно*" и не надо миксов **3 в 1**: HTML+JS+CSS.

```
.kolvo {
    margin-left:7px; 
    margin-right:7px;
    width: 175px;
}
```

Comment: по-моему `$('.kolvo').on('keyup', function(){})` не будет навешен на динамически созданные элементы, или будет?

и ещё лучше заменить:

    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\D/, ''));

на:
  
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/, '');

Comment: Что бы замена работала глобально, а так же при CTRL+V нужно добавить модификатор g: `$(this).val($(this).val().replace (/\D/g, ''));`

Answer (score 2):

```js
function cislo(){
    if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57)
    event.returnValue= false;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onKeyPress="cislo()">
```

Comment: Но я могу сюда скопировать текст, и он вставится в поле.

Comment: Еще один из вариантов: - [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/966598/244950)

Answer (score 1):

Еще один из вариантов:

```js
document.oninput = function() {
var input = document.querySelector('.input-0');
input.value = input.value.replace (/\D/g, '');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input-0">
```

Вариант без JavaScript:

```html
  <label for="quantity">Количество (от 1 до 5):</label>
  <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```